# ОШИБКА 400 BAD REQUEST

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis

Всем привет! Я запускаю сайт Asp.net framework на iis сервере. и у меня при стандартной asp регистрации вылетатет ошибка, написанная в заголовке. Как это исправить? Я нашел только следующее:

Для Интернет-информационных услуг (IIS) 6.0 и более поздних, ключи реестра MaxFieldLength и MaxRequestBytes расположены в следующем подключе:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\HTTP\Parameters

Подскажите, где расположены эти папки или файлы? и правильно ли я сделаю, если просто добавлю эти 2 параметра

Comment: Я вообще не могу найти эти файлы.

Comment: Это не файлы, а раздел в реестре винды. Нажмите `Win + R` в строке наберите `regedit` и запустите редактор реестра. Только смотрите внимательно! Не измените лишнее, иначе можете нарушить работы всей системы!

Comment: У IIS есть ведь логи, надо в логах смотреть, что пишет.

Comment: Не понятно ни что вы сделали, ни что за ошибка у вас, ни где именно вы нашли тот текст, что показываете, ни что вы.за сайт используете, ни какие запросы и какой длины посылаете. Вы сами понимаете, что вы ничего по сути не спросили?